# Application of bounded inverse theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, and that $T\in \mathscr B(X,Y)$. Rudin claims that if the range of $T,\ \mathscr R (T),$ is closed then "it follows that" there is a $c\in \mathbb R^+$ such that for all $y\in \mathscr R (T)$ there is an $x\in X$ such that $y=Tx$ and $\left \| x \right \|\le c\left \| y\right \|$.

I want to fill in the details:

$T:X\to \mathscr R (T)$ is an open mapping since the range of $T$ is closed and $Y$ is complete. One observes that if $T$ is injective, the result is an application of the open mapping theorem to say that $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

Otherwise, consider the Banach space $X/\ker T$ with the quotient norm and define  $\tilde{T}:X/\ker T\to T(X)$ by  $\tilde{T}(x+\ker f)=T(x)$.

$\ \tilde{T}$ is well-defined and injective, and $\left \| \tilde{T} \right \|\le \left \| T \right \|$. Furthermore, $T=\tilde{T}\circ \pi,$ where $\pi:X\to X/\ker T$ is the canonical projection. Now, if $W$ is open in $X/\ker T$, then $\pi^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X$, and therefore $\tilde{T}(W)=\tilde{T}(\pi\circ \pi^{-1}(W))=T(\pi^{-1}(W))$ is open in $\mathscr R (T)$, and so now we are in the situation of the first observation with $\tilde{T}$ in place of $T$ and the result follows as soon as we choose a particular $x_1\in x+\ker T$.

Comment: Your first claim that $T$ is an open mapping is incorrect. Think about the map $T:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $x \mapsto (x,0)$. In fact, the initial claim can't possibly be right as written since not all bounded operators are surjective, so there does not exist an $x\in X$ such that $y=Tx$ for a $y\in Y$.

Comment: But $T:X\to \mathscr R (T)$ is surjective and open since $\mathscr R (T)$ is closed and $Y$ is complete. I meant to write $y\in \mathscr R (T)$ thanks I will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tilde{T}$ has a bounded inverse, since $\mathscr R (T)$ is closed.

Let $c:=||\tilde{T}^{-1}||+1$

If $y \in \mathscr R (T)$ and $y \ne 0$, let $a:= \tilde{T}^{-1}(y)$ . Then there is $z \in X$ with $a=z+ \ker (T)$. This gives

$||z+ \ker (T)|| \le ||\tilde{T}^{-1}||*||y|| < c||y||$

Since $||z+ \ker (T)||= \inf\{||x||: x \in z+ \ker(T)\}$ we find $x \in z+ \ker (T)$ such that

$(*)$  $||x|| \le c||y||$ .

Furthermore we have $Tx=Tz=\tilde{T}(a)=y$

Now , if $y=0$, then $(*)$ also holds (with $x=0$):

Comment: Thanks for the thorough (and clear) response. You mean $||z+ \ker (T)|| \le ||\tilde{T}^{-1}||*||y|| < c||y||$ in the fourth line right?

Comment: Ooops ! Yes, I mean $||\tilde{T}^{-1}||$